# Aggregated Means Differ in Regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, difference-in-difference, aggregation

I try to run a difference-in-difference model based on single observations which I have to aggregate in order to generate an outcome variable "w.mortf" = mortality.
My original data set provides a total average value that is completely different after aggregation i.e. in the different groups.
Thus running a regression on the second aggregated data set provides values (e.g. mortalitly of 4%) to which one cannot relate to using the average values from the inital data frame (overall mortality of 1%).
Please refer to an example data set in:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338270/dplyr-difference-mutate-and-summarize-in-group-by

Thanks for your endeavours!

Comment: A question should be self-contained. Referring readers to another post is not appreciated.

Comment: Thank you and I understand. It was just illustrating the above basic question. The other post was originally meant to be a tool question however  I mainly wanted to avoid copy-paste.